# Keras: the difference between LSTM dropout and LSTM recurrent dropout

Tags: keras, lstm, dropout

From the Keras documentation:

dropout: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the units to drop for the
 linear transformation of the inputs.

recurrent_dropout: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the units to
 drop for the linear transformation of the recurrent state.

Can anyone point to where on the image below each dropout happens?

[image]

Comment: `for the linear transformation of the inputs` so x_t

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at (the first part of) [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.05287.pdf). Regular dropout is applied on the inputs and/or the outputs, meaning the vertical arrows from `x_t` and to `h_t`. In your case, if you add it as an argument to your layer, it will mask the inputs; you can add a Dropout layer after your recurrent layer to mask the outputs as well. Recurrent dropout masks (or "drops") the connections between the recurrent units; that would be the horizontal arrows in your picture.

This picture is taken from the paper above. On the left, regular dropout on inputs and outputs. On the right, regular dropout PLUS recurrent dropout:

[image: This picture is taken from the paper above. On the left, regular dropout on inputs and outputs. On the right, regular dropout PLUS recurrent dropout.]

(Ignore the colour of the arrows in this case; in the paper they are making a further point of keeping the same dropout masks at each timestep)

Comment: Thanks, @michetonu. The linked paper and your explanation were helpful. Anything you could point to in terms of how to properly use regular dropout with recurrent_dropout in Keras for time series forecasting? Seems some examples out there combine the two kinds of dropout, whiles use just recurrent_dropout.

Comment: @KimMiller from what I've encountered, there does not seem to be much science behind using one or another, and how much (yet). I tend to optimize both and choose whatever combination works best.

Comment: And there seems to be applying the (regular) dropout= parameter on a layer vs. a dropout layer by itself. What is the effective difference between these methods?

Answer (score 18):

Above answer highlights one of the recurrent dropout methods but that one is NOT used by tensorflow and keras. [Tensorflow Doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/rnn/LayerNormLSTMCell).

Keras/TF refers a recurrent method proposed by [Semeniuta et al](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05118). Also, check below the image comparing different recurrent dropout methods. The [Gal and Ghahramani](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.05287.pdf) method which is mentioned in above answer is at second position and Semeniuta method is the right most.

[image]