# How visualize attention LSTM using keras-self-attention package?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, attention-model

I'm using [(keras-self-attention)](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-self-attention) to implement attention LSTM in KERAS. How can I visualize the attention part after training the model? This is a time series forecasting case.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras_self_attention import SeqWeightedAttention
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Flatten

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(activation = 'tanh' ,units = 200, return_sequences = True, 
               input_shape = (TrainD[0].shape[1], TrainD[0].shape[2])))
model.add(SeqSelfAttention())
model.add(Flatten())    
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One approach is to fetch the outputs of `SeqSelfAttention` for a given input, and organize them so to display predictions *per-channel* (see below). For something more advanced, have a look at the [iNNvestigate library](https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate) (usage examples included).

**Update**: I can also recommend [See RNN](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn), a package I wrote.

---

**Explanation**:
`show_features_1D` fetches `layer_name` (can be a substring) layer outputs and shows predictions per-channel (labeled), with timesteps along x-axis and output values along y-axis.

- `input_data` = *single batch* of data of shape `(1, input_shape)`
- `prefetched_outputs` = already-acquired layer outputs; overrides `input_data`
- `max_timesteps` = max # of timesteps to show
- `max_col_subplots` = max # of subplots along horizontal
- `equate_axes` = force all x- and y- axes to be equal (recommended for fair comparison)
- `show_y_zero` = whether to show y=0 as a red line
- `channel_axis` = layer features dimension (e.g. `units` for LSTM, which is last)
- `scale_width, scale_height` = scale displayed image width & height
- `dpi` = image quality (dots per inches)

---

**Visuals (below) explanation**:

- First is useful to see the *shapes* of extracted features, regardless of magnitude - giving information about e.g. *frequency* contents
- Second is useful to see *feature relationships* - e.g. relative magnitudes, biases, and frequencies. Below result stands in stark contrast with image above it, as, running `print(outs_1)` reveals that all magnitudes are very small and don't vary much, so including the y=0 point and equating axes yields a line-like visual, which can be interpreted as self-attention being bias-oriented.
- Third is useful for visualizing features too many to be visualized as above; defining model with `batch_shape` instead of `input_shape` removes all `?` in printed shapes, and we can see that first output's shape is `(10, 60, 240)`, second's `(10, 240, 240)`. In other words, the first output returns LSTM channel attention, and the second a "timesteps attention". The heatmap result below can be interpreted as showing attention "cooling down" w.r.t. timesteps.

---

**SeqWeightedAttention** is a lot easier to visualize, but there isn't much to visualize; you'll need to rid of `Flatten` above to make it work. The attention's output shapes then become `(10, 60)` and `(10, 240)` - for which you can use a simple histogram, `plt.hist` (just make sure you exclude the batch dimension - i.e. feed `(60,)` or `(240,)`).

---

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Flatten, concatenate
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention
import numpy as np 

ipt   = Input(shape=(240,4))
x     = LSTM(60, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(ipt)
x     = SeqSelfAttention(return_attention=True)(x)
x     = concatenate(x)
x     = Flatten()(x)
out   = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(ipt,out)
model.compile(Adam(lr=1e-2), loss='binary_crossentropy')

X = np.random.rand(10,240,4) # dummy data
Y = np.random.randint(0,2,(10,1)) # dummy labels
model.train_on_batch(X, Y)

outs = get_layer_outputs(model, 'seq', X[0:1], 1)
outs_1 = outs[0]
outs_2 = outs[1]

show_features_1D(model,'lstm',X[0:1],max_timesteps=100,equate_axes=False,show_y_zero=False)
show_features_1D(model,'lstm',X[0:1],max_timesteps=100,equate_axes=True, show_y_zero=True)
show_features_2D(outs_2[0])  # [0] for 2D since 'outs_2' is 3D
```

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

```
def show_features_1D(model=None, layer_name=None, input_data=None,
                     prefetched_outputs=None, max_timesteps=100,
                     max_col_subplots=10, equate_axes=False,
                     show_y_zero=True, channel_axis=-1,
                     scale_width=1, scale_height=1, dpi=76):
    if prefetched_outputs is None:
        layer_outputs = get_layer_outputs(model, layer_name, input_data, 1)[0]
    else:
        layer_outputs = prefetched_outputs
    n_features    = layer_outputs.shape[channel_axis]

    for _int in range(1, max_col_subplots+1):
      if (n_features/_int).is_integer():
        n_cols = int(n_features/_int)
    n_rows = int(n_features/n_cols)

    fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows,n_cols,sharey=equate_axes,dpi=dpi)
    fig.set_size_inches(24*scale_width,16*scale_height)

    subplot_idx = 0
    for row_idx in range(axes.shape[0]):
      for col_idx in range(axes.shape[1]): 
        subplot_idx += 1
        feature_output = layer_outputs[:,subplot_idx-1]
        feature_output = feature_output[:max_timesteps]
        ax = axes[row_idx,col_idx]

        if show_y_zero:
            ax.axhline(0,color='red')
        ax.plot(feature_output)

        ax.axis(xmin=0,xmax=len(feature_output))
        ax.axis('off')

        ax.annotate(str(subplot_idx),xy=(0,.99),xycoords='axes fraction',
                    weight='bold',fontsize=14,color='g')
    if equate_axes:
        y_new = []
        for row_axis in axes:
            y_new += [np.max(np.abs([col_axis.get_ylim() for 
                                     col_axis in row_axis]))]
        y_new = np.max(y_new)
        for row_axis in axes:
            [col_axis.set_ylim(-y_new,y_new) for col_axis in row_axis]
    plt.show()
```

```py
def show_features_2D(data, cmap='bwr', norm=None,
                     scale_width=1, scale_height=1):
    if norm is not None:
        vmin, vmax = norm
    else:
        vmin, vmax = None, None  # scale automatically per min-max of 'data'

    plt.imshow(data, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
    plt.xlabel('Timesteps', weight='bold', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('Attention features', weight='bold', fontsize=14)
    plt.colorbar(fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)  # works for any size plot

    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8*scale_width, 8*scale_height)
    plt.show()
```

---

```py
def get_layer_outputs(model, layer_name, input_data, learning_phase=1):
    outputs   = [layer.output for layer in model.layers if layer_name in layer.name]
    layers_fn = K.function([model.input, K.learning_phase()], outputs)
    return layers_fn([input_data, learning_phase])
```

---

**SeqWeightedAttention example** per request:

```py
ipt   = Input(batch_shape=(10,240,4))
x     = LSTM(60, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True)(ipt)
x     = SeqWeightedAttention(return_attention=True)(x)
x     = concatenate(x)
out   = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(ipt,out)
model.compile(Adam(lr=1e-2), loss='binary_crossentropy')

X = np.random.rand(10,240,4) # dummy data
Y = np.random.randint(0,2,(10,1)) # dummy labels
model.train_on_batch(X, Y)

outs = get_layer_outputs(model, 'seq', X, 1)
outs_1 = outs[0][0] # additional index since using batch_shape
outs_2 = outs[1][0]

plt.hist(outs_1, bins=500); plt.show()
plt.hist(outs_2, bins=500); plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. Considering time series, we can have two attention vectors: 'attention vector of factors(input/features)' and 'attention vector of times'. How can I extract these attention vectors separately?

Comment: @user2991243 I've never used attention myself, so unsure what you refer to - but can answer nonetheless if you provide me the output shape of the attention layer (e.g. `print(model.layers[1].output.shape)`). The idea will be to "divide and concur"

Comment: The shape of attention layer: `(?, ?, 200)`. In this specific case, I have 243 features and also using LSTM with 200 units.

Comment: @user2991243 I just loaded up your attention layer, and it appears the functionality you describe requires `return_attention=True` - correct? Else the layer seems to apply only one transformation that cannot be meaningfully divided in two

Comment: Yes but it returns this error: `All layers in a Sequential model should have a single output tensor. For multi-output layers, use the functional API,` when I activate this option.

Comment: @user2991243 Yeah, I'm testing right now - you'll need a `concatenate` layer. Also I'd strongly recommend using the Model API (`Model`) for most purposes, as it's easier to use advanced functionality - but Sequential will work here also. So to confirm: `return_attention=True` returns two outputs, and these two are what you refer to? If so, I'll update the answer with the complete example

Comment: So you think I should add concaterate layer between Attention and Flatten layer?

Comment: @user2991243 Yes, I tested and it works - now it's a question of your usage (see previous comment)

Comment: There is a problem here. As a time series case, if you change the shape of lstm to `(1, 240)` and the shape of input data to `(10,1,240)`, the attention layer always return one. In this case, we have 240 features and 10 samples.

Comment: Probably it's because this new layer is defined for classification but how can I change it to my new case? (As you can see, if we change one to two, it will fix the issue but it's not my case).

Comment: @user2991243 If `batch_shape` is `(10,1,240)`, you are feeding 1 timestep w/ 240 features - to which your LSTM's output shape should be `(10, 1, 200)`. Then it appears to make sense for the weighted attention layer to output `(10, 1, 1)` (as its pattern seems to be `(batch_size, timesteps, timesteps)`), and the value of "1" maybe means 100% of attention on one timestep. The first weighted attention output however isn't just 1, and has output shape `(10, 1, 200)`

Comment: That's correct. But suppose that we have a time series dataframe with 10 days and (x rows) and 240 features (y rows). How can we convert it to a structure which is appropriate for this case? We usually change it to the mentioned structure using reshape function, but it seems this doesn't work here (`X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))`).

Comment: @user2991243 That's taking the question substantially outside its original scope, and SO isn't intended for extended back-forths. For your question of model design, I can refer you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58276337/proper-way-to-feed-time-series-data-to-stateful-lstm/58277760#58277760) - but in a nutshell, depends what you're trying to accomplish: treat each of 10 days as independent, or causally related. The question of visualization, however, appears resolved.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I am not sure if this is the appropriate place to ask... But... If the problem is a "many-to-one Seq2Seq" one, how can we modify the visualization?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh See the "SeqWeightedAttention" section. As an alternative to a histogram, you can use [`show_features_0D()`](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn/blob/master/see_rnn/visuals_gen.py#L10) (see EX6 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017288/how-to-visualize-rnn-lstm-gradients-in-keras-tensorflow/#answer-59017289)).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, Thanks for your valuable response. When I tried your example, I have ''' ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`. ''' Do you have any clue why this error occurred?

Comment: @KooroshAslansefat Reports are handled at [Github](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn/issues).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon, thanks for your reply. I will add it as an issue in Github.