# How can I compare weights of different Keras models?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've saved numbers of models in .h5 format. I want to compare their characteristics such as weight.
I don't have any Idea how I can appropriately compare them specially in the form of tables and figures.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You probably won't be able to discern anything of value just by looking at a raw list of weights. There are an infinite number of ways to process the weights, and each can be useful or not for different reasons. Without knowing why you want to look at the weights, we can't tell you the best way to do so.

Comment: What layers does your model include?

Comment: I've used different models for different types of data, but I think the weights of models are close to each other. If it is I don't need different models for each type of data. They include conv2d, maxpool2d, dense, flatten.

Comment: Without providing further information on your model - minimally, the layers you use (Dense, LSTM, etc) - the question is too broad. Naming the application (regression, classification, etc) would also help

Comment: I will provide it in the form of figure a few minutes later. But I don't think it depends on the structure I've used I just want to compare two similar models with different weights.

Comment: Notify users of your response with @name, by the way - randomly re-checked question to see your response

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon  a png file has been added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Weight-introspection is a fairly advanced endeavor, and requires model-specific treatment. Visualizing weights is a largely technical challenge, but what you do with that information's a different matter - I'll address largely the former, but touch upon the latter.

**Update**: I also recommend [See RNN](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn) for weights, gradients, and activations visualization.

---

**Visualizing weights**: one approach is as follows:

1. Retrieve weights of layer of interest. *Ex*: `model.layers[1].get_weights()`
2. Understand weight roles and dimensionality. *Ex*: LSTMs have three sets of weights: `kernel`, `recurrent`, and `bias`, each serving a different purpose. *Within* each weight matrix are *gate* weights - Input, Cell, Forget, Output. For Conv layers, the distinction's between filters (dim0), kernels, and strides.
3. Organize weight matrices for visualization in a meaningful manner per (2). *Ex*: for Conv, unlike for LSTM, feature-specific treatment isn't really necessary, and we can simply flatten kernel weights and bias weights and visualize them in a histogram
4. Select visualization method: histogram, heatmap, scatterplot, etc - for flattened data, a histogram is the best bet

---

**Interpreting weights**: a few approaches are:

- *Sparsity*: if weight norm ("average") is low, the model is sparse. May or may not be beneficial.
- *Health*: if too many weights are zero or near-zero, it's a sign of too many dead neurons; this can be useful for debugging, as once a layer's in such a state, it usually does not revert - so training should be restarted
- *Stability*: if weights are changing greatly and quickly, or if there are many high-valued weights, it may indicate impaired gradient performance, remedied by e.g. gradient clipping or weight constraints

---

**Model comparison**: there isn't a way for simply looking at two weights from separate models side-by-side and deciding "this is the better one"; analyze each model separately, for example as above, then decide which one's ups outweigh downs.

The ultimate tiebreaker, however, will be *validation performance* - and it's also the more practical one. It goes as:

1. Train model for several hyperparameter configurations
2. Select one with best validation performance
3. Fine-tune that model (e.g. via further hyperparameter configs)

Weight visualization should be mainly kept as a debugging or logging tool - as, put simply, even with our best current understanding of neural networks one cannot tell how well the model will generalize just by looking at the weights.

---

**Suggestion**: also visualize layer *outputs* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356868/how-visualize-attention-lstm-using-keras-self-attention-package/58357581#58357581) and sample output at bottom.

---

**Visual example**:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

ipt = Input(shape=(16, 16, 16))
x   = Conv2D(12, 8, 1)(ipt)
x   = Flatten()(x)
out = Dense(16)(x)

model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('adam', 'mse')

X = np.random.randn(10, 16, 16, 16)  # toy data
Y = np.random.randn(10, 16)  # toy labels
for _ in range(10):
    model.train_on_batch(X, Y)

def get_weights_print_stats(layer):
    W = layer.get_weights()
    print(len(W))
    for w in W:
        print(w.shape)
    return W

def hist_weights(weights, bins=500):
    for weight in weights:
        plt.hist(np.ndarray.flatten(weight), bins=bins)

W = get_weights_print_stats(model.layers[1])
# 2
# (8, 8, 16, 12)
# (12,)

hist_weights(W)
```

---

[image]

---

**Conv1D outputs visualization**: ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356868/how-visualize-attention-lstm-using-keras-self-attention-package/58357581#58357581))

[image]

Comment: May I ask you to provide me some resources for further information? thanks in advance. @OverLordGoldDragon

Comment: In addition to one I provided, sure: [iNNvestigate](https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate) module; [TF saliency maps](https://github.com/PAIR-code/saliency)

Answer (score 0):

To compare weights of two models, I vectorize model weights (i.e., create 1D array) for each model.  Then, I calculate the percent difference between respective weights and construct a histogram of these percent differences.  If all values are close to zero, there is suggestion (but not proof) that the models are practically the same.  This is just one approach out of many for comparing models using their weights.

As an aside, I will note that I use this method when I want some indication that my model has converged on a global, rather than local, minimum.  I will train models with several different initializations.  If all the initializations result in convergence to the same weights, it suggests that the minimum is a global minimum.