# Visualizing neural network using python

Tags: python, neural-network, visualization

I'm implementing an algorithm to classify messages into topics using a neural network. 
I'm wondering if there are library to help me visualize the training process like the one you can find [here](http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4,2&seed=0.72802&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false):

I'm going to do the classification of three-dimensional data instead of two-dimension. How can we do it?

Also, in the link above, I don't understand the first layer input where we have a fixed horizontal line and a vertical line perception. Can we set out the first layer of the neural network to be like that using sci-kit learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but any good one won't be nearly as simple as the linked playground, and will require some familiarization. Below is a list of such libraries, & links to my answers w/ visualization functions you could adapt to your application:

- [iNNvestigate](https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate), classifier introspection (first image below)
- [Saliency maps](https://raghakot.github.io/keras-vis/visualizations/activation_maximization/), extracted features introspection
- [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/), full model introspection, highly configurable, but complex
- [LSTM/CNN Visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356868/how-visualize-attention-lstm-using-keras-self-attention-package/58357581#58357581), simple function (second image below)
- [Weights visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58401393/keras-how-can-i-comapre-weights-of-different-models?noredirect=1&lq=1), simple function

(Answer assumes you're using TensorFlow)

---

[image]
[image]