# How to identify important features in LSTM

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, data-visualization, lstm

I have a binary classification problem where for each data point I have 3 time-series as follows.

```
data_point,   time_series1,      time_series2,      time_series3,  label
d1,         [0.1, ....., 0.5], [0.8, ....., 0.6], [0.8, ....., 0.8], 1
and so on
```

I am using the following code to perform my binary classification.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(25,4)))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Since, currently I am considering my classification as a black-box task, I would like to dig deeper and see what happens inside.

More specifically, I would like to know the imporatant features used by LSTM to classify my datapoints. More importantly I want to answer the following questions;

- Which time series (i.e. `time_series1`, `time_series2`,
  `time_series3`) was most influenced in the classification
- What are features extracted from the most influenced timeseries?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Attention Mechanism** is used for this exactly; programmatic implementation isn't simple, but use-ready repositories exist - see below. Example output below.

As to what attention 'is', see [this SE answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344508/what-are-attention-mechanisms-exactly), and/or [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-exactly-the-attention-mechanism-introduced-to-RNN-recurrent-neural-network-It-would-be-nice-if-you-could-make-it-easy-to-understand); in a nutshell, it's a means of identifying the most 'important' timesteps, effectively mapping out a temporal 'heatmap'.

- [iNNvestigate](https://github.com/albermax/innvestigate), classifier introspection (first image below; can be applied to timeseries)
- [Saliency maps](https://raghakot.github.io/keras-vis/visualizations/activation_maximization/), extracted features introspection
- [LSTM/CNN Visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58356868/how-visualize-attention-lstm-using-keras-self-attention-package/58357581#58357581), simple function (second image below)
- [LSTM_Attention](https://github.com/ningshixian/LSTM_Attention) - includes research paper-specific implementations.

Lastly, as a tip, ditch LSTMs for [IndRNNs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04831); where former struggles w/ 800-1000 timesteps, latter's shown to succeed w/ 5000+. Features are also more interpretable, as each channel is independent, absent LSTM-type gating mechanisms. Though if speed is important, there is no [`CuDNNIndRNN`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#cudnnlstm).

---

[image]
[image]