# How can I setup a Dense bottleneck in a stacked LSTM with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, autoencoder

I have:

```
        self.model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm1_size, input_shape=(
            seq_length, feature_dim), return_sequences=True)))
        self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.model.add(Bidirectional(
            LSTM(lstm2_size, return_sequences=True)))
        self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        # BOTTLENECK HERE

        self.model.add(Bidirectional(
            LSTM(lstm3_size, return_sequences=True)))
        self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.model.add(Bidirectional(
            LSTM(lstm4_size, return_sequences=True)))
        self.model.add(BatchNormalization())
        self.model.add(Dropout(0.2))

        self.model.add(Dense(feature_dim, activation='linear'))
```

However, I want to set up an `autoencoder`-like setup, without having to have 2 separate models.  Where I have the comment `BOTTLENECK HERE`, I want to have a vector of some dimension, say `bottleneck_dim`.

After that, it should be some LSTM layers that then reconstruct a sequence, of the same dimensions as the initial input. However, I believe that adding a `Dense` layer will not return one vector, but instead return vectors for each of the sequence-length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `Dense` has been updated to automatically act as if wrapped with `TimeDistributed` - i.e. you'll get `(batch_size, seq_length, lstm2_size)`.
- A workaround is to place a `Flatten()` before it, so `Dense`'s output shape will be `(batch_size, seq_length * lstm2_size)`. I wouldn't recommend it, however, as it's likely to corrupt temporal information (you're mixing channels and timesteps). Further, it constrains the network to `seq_length`, so you can no longer do training or inference on any other `seq_length`.

A preferred alternative is `Bidirectional(LSTM(..., return_sequences=False))`, which returns only the last timestep's output, shaped `(batch_size, lstm_bottleneck_size)`. To feed its outputs to the next LSTM, you'll need  [`RepeatVector(seq_length)`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#repeatvector) after the `=False` layer.

Do mind the extent of the "bottleneck", though; e.g. if `(seq_length, feature_dim) = (200, 64)` and `lstm_bottleneck_size = 400`, that's `(1 * 400) / (200 * 64)` = **x32** reduction, which is quite large, and may overwhelm the network. I'd suggest with x8 as the goal.

Comment: So then where I have `BOTTLENECK HERE`, you're saying that my `lstm2` should instead simple do `return_sequences=False`? Will that be fed in easily to the next LSTM layer?

Comment: Secondly, is there any benefit to compressing to a bottleneck then reconstructing it? Or am I better off just doing straight seq2seq?

Comment: seq2seq should be easier to train for longer timesteps, as loss contributes to gradient to each timestep directly, though it also depends on your [regularization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714407/rnn-regularization-which-component-to-regularize/58868383#58868383). You can try both though, just keep it a fair comparison with a fixed compression ratio. The idea with autoencoders is to impose some form of a constraint for the encoder to learn robust/useful representations - dimension's one of them; others include denoising (`GaussianNoise`, input dropout), sparsity (`SpatialDropout`).

Comment: Can you clarify the role of `RepeatVector`? Now instead of feeding 1 vector, I'll be feeding `seq_length` of the same vectors?

Comment: How do I specify the `lstm_bottleneck_size`?

Comment: @Shamoon Correct @RepeatVector, and `lstm_bottleneck_size` determines the "compression factor", which you tune as a hyperparameter; see example in my answer.

Comment: So where exactly do I specify my bottleneck size? Is it a parameter in the last layer before the RepeatVector?

Comment: @Shamoon Yes, and previous `size`s should be increasing toward input; I suggest reading further on autoencoders, e.g. [here](https://www.kaggle.com/shivamb/how-autoencoders-work-intro-and-usecases)