# Keras LSTM: dropout vs recurrent_dropout

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, dropout

I realize this post is asking a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924690/keras-the-difference-between-lstm-dropout-and-lstm-recurrent-dropout).

But I just wanted some clarification, preferably a link to some kind of Keras documentation that says the difference.

In my mind, `dropout` works between neurons. And `recurrent_dropout` works each neurons between timesteps. But, I have no grounding for this whatsoever.

The documentation on the [Keras webite](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 4):

Keras [LSTM](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstm) documentation contains high-level explanation:

> **dropout**: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the units to drop for the linear transformation of the inputs.
>
> **recurrent_dropout**: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the units to drop for the linear transformation
>   of the recurrent state.

But this totally corresponds to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44924690/712995) you refer to:

> Regular dropout is applied on the inputs and/or the outputs, meaning the vertical arrows from `x_t` and to `h_t`. ...
>
> Recurrent dropout masks (or "drops") the connections between the recurrent units; that would be the horizontal arrows in your picture.

If you're interested in details on the formula level, the best way is to inspect the source code: [`keras/layers/recurrent.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1847), look for `rec_dp_mask` (recurrent dropout mask) and `dp_mask`. One is affecting the `h_tm1` (the previous memory cell), the other affects the `inputs`.