# Avoid overfitting in sequence to sequence problem using keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, supervised-learning

I'm having a problem with a model I want to train.

It's a typical seq-to-seq problem with an attention layer, where the input is a string, and the output is a substring from the submitted string.

e.g.

```
Input            Ground Truth
-----------------------------
helloimchuck     chuck
johnismyname     john
```

(This is just a dummy data, not a real part of the dataset ^^)

And the model looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(hidden_size, return_sequences=True), merge_mode='concat',
                        input_shape=(None, input_size)))  # Encoder
model.add(Attention())
model.add(RepeatVector(max_out_seq_len))
model.add(GRU(hidden_size * 2, return_sequences=True))  # Decoder
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=output_size, activation="softmax")))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The problem is this here:

[image]

As you can see, there is overfitting.

I'm using early stop criteria on the validation loss with `patience=8`.

```
self.Early_stop_criteria = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0,
                                                             patience=8, verbose=0,
                                                             mode='auto')
```

And I'm using one-hot-vector to fit the model.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 64
HIDDEN_DIM = 128
```

The thing is, I've tried with other batch sizes, other hidden dimensions, a dataset of 10K rows, 15K rows, 25K rows and now 50K rows. However, there is always overfitting, and I don't know why.

The `test_size = 0.2` and the `validation_split=0.2`. Those are the only parameters I haven't changed.

I'm also made me sure that the dataset properly build.

The only idea that I have is trying with another validation split, maybe `0.33` instead of `0.2`.

I don't know if `cross-validation` would help.

Maybe anyone has a better idea, what I could try. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried dropout or batchnorm?

Comment: Not really. Would you use it just between the input and the first hidden layer?

Comment: There are 2 types of dropout you can use. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44929759/10111931) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50721621/10111931) for more details on what the difference is and how to use them with Keras and where we can use them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kvish proposed, dropout was a good solution.

I first tried with a dropout of 0.2.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(GRU(hidden_size, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2), merge_mode='concat',
                            input_shape=(None, input_size)))  # Encoder
model.add(Attention())
model.add(RepeatVector(max_out_seq_len))
model.add(GRU(hidden_size * 2, return_sequences=True))  # Decoder
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=output_size, activation="softmax")))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And with 50K rows, it worked, but still had overfitting.

So, I tried with a dropout of 0.33, and it worked perfectly.