# What's the mean of “ recurrent dropout” of LSTM?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

Recently，I try to use the “*tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell*” ， but I don't know what's the mean of the argument “dropout_keep_prob”.

Then I look at the Document given by Google. Their explanation is “unit Tensor or float between 0 and 1 representing the ***recurrent dropout*** probability value. If float and 1.0, no dropout will be applied.”

But I don't know the difference between “**recurrent dropout**” and“**dropout**”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras: the difference between LSTM dropout and LSTM recurrent dropout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924690/keras-the-difference-between-lstm-dropout-and-lstm-recurrent-dropout)

Answer (score 0):

`Recurrent Dropout` is a regularization method for recurrent neural networks. `Dropout` is applied to the updates to LSTM memory cells, i.e. it drops out the input/update gate in LSTM. For more information you can refer [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05118v2).